# Outlook time zone settings changed pop alert

Tags: ms-office, timezone

Everyday I'm getting the following pop up message, although I'm not changing any time zone settings. Countless number of times I tried both options (Don't update/Update) but I still cannot get rid of this message.
Working years with Outlook on PC & never had this kind of issues.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to update Outlook ?

Comment: yes it's updated